# Edit Profile: Radio button checked with ajax and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, radio-button

**level: beginner**

I've tried to view my user profile data from database to html page using ajax in javascript file, so that user can update it.
I can view the profile with ajax and can update it with javascript. But the information with **radio button can't be changed.** When I choose another value, it select **"multiple value"**, so it can't be updated coz they said there are a null value in it.

**How can I edit/change the value of radio button (jenis kelamin and golongan darah), without multiple value and error in database update?**

I don't know what's wrong with it. Could you help me? Here's my codes.

**Thank you.**

My php code in server side: **newpass.php as a controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class newpass extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('newpass_model','npmod');
    }

    //to get the user profile
    public function read() {
        $iduser = $this->session->userdata('id');
        if(isset($iduser))
        echo json_encode($this->npmod->getByIdUser($iduser));
    }

    //to edit the user profile
    public function update() {
        $s = $this->npmod->update();
        echo $s;
    }       
}
?>
```

My php code in server side: **newpass_model.php as a model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class newpass_model extends CI_Model {

    //to get the user profile
    function getByIdUser($iduser) {
        $iduser = intval( $iduser );

        $query = $this->db->where('iduser',$iduser)->limit( 1 )->get('pasien');

        if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
            //return $query->row();
            $row = $query->row();

            $tgl = $row->tgllahir;
            $myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $tgl);
            $newDateString = $myDateTime->format('d-m-Y');

            $data = array(
            'nama' => $row->nama,
            'tempatlahir' => $row->tempatlahir,
            'tgllahir' => $newDateString,
            'jeniskelamin' => $row->jeniskelamin,
            'tinggi_badan' => $row->tinggi_badan,
            'berat_badan' => $row->berat_badan,
            'goldarah' => $row->goldarah,
            'kontak' => $row->kontak,
            'nokontak_kel' => $row->nokontak_kel,
            'email_kel' => $row->email_kel
            );
            return $data;

        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }   

    //to edit the user profile
    public function update() {  
    $iduser = $this->session->userdata('id');

    $tgl = $this->input->post('tanggal');
    $myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $tgl);
    $newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d');  

    $jkl = $this->input->post('jeniskelaminL');
    $jkp = $this->input->post('jeniskelaminP');
    if($jkl==''){
        $jk=$jkp;
    }else{
        $jk=$jkl;
    }
    $golA = $this->input->post('golonganA');
    $golB = $this->input->post('golonganB');
    $golAB = $this->input->post('golonganAB');
    $golO = $this->input->post('golonganO');

    if($golA!=''){
        $gol=$golA;
    }else if($golB!=''){
        $gol=$golB;
    }else if($golAB!=''){
        $gol=$golAB;
    }else {
        $gol=$golO;
    }

        $data = array(
            'nama' => $this->input->post('nama'),
            'tempatlahir' => $this->input->post('tempat'),
            'tgllahir' => $newDateString,
            'jeniskelamin' => $jk,
            'tinggi_badan' => $this->input->post('tinggi'),
            'berat_badan' => $this->input->post('berat'),
            'goldarah' => $gol,
            'kontak' => $this->input->post('kontak'),
            'nokontak_kel' => $this->input->post('kontak_kel'),
            'email_kel' => $this->input->post('kontak_em')
            );

        if($this->input->post('nama')=='' || $this->input->post('tempat')=='' || $newDateString=='' || $jk=='' || 
        $this->input->post('tinggi')=='' || $this->input->post('berat')=='' || $gol=='' || $this->input->post('kontak')=='' ||
        $this->input->post('kontak_kel')=='' || $this->input->post('kontak_em')=='')
        {
            echo "0";           
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->where('iduser',$iduser);
            $this->db->update('pasien',$data);
            if ($this->db->affected_rows() >= '1') 
            {
            echo "1"; 
            }else{
            echo "0"; 
            }

        }

   }
}
?>
```

My javascript code in client side: **editprofile.js**

```
/*Don't forget to add set_ip.js and jquery before you use this script in HTML page to make it work*/
var urlini = seturl();
var part= 'newpass/';

var readUrl   = urlini+part+'read';    

$( function() {  
    readUsers();
}); //end document ready

//to update profile
function update_profile() {
    alert("click tombol simpan");
    name = /^([-a-z0-9_-]{5,50})+$/i.test($("#nama").val());
    bb = /^([-0-9_-])+$/i.test($("#berat").val());

    var form_reg =  $("input").val();
    if(form_reg == "")
    {
        alert("Semua data harus diisi.");
    }
    else if(!name || !bb)
    {
        alert("Terdapat kesalahan atau data kosong pada pengisian data.\nPastikan password Anda sesuai.");
    }
    else
    {       
        $.post(urlini+part+'update',
            $('#edit_profile').serialize(),function(msg){
            if(msg == '1')
            {               
                alert("Data berhasil disimpan!");
                window.location="home.html";
            }
            else if(msg == '0')
            {
                alert("Masih ada data yang kosong.");
            }
        });
    }
}

function readUsers() {
$.ajax({
        url: readUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function( response ) {

                $( '#nama' ).val( response.nama);
                $( '#tempat' ).val( response.tempatlahir);
                $( '#tanggal' ).val( response.tgllahir);
            if(response.jeniskelamin=="L"){
                $('input:radio[name=jeniskelaminL]')[0].checked = true;             
            }else{
                $('input:radio[name=jeniskelaminP]')[0].checked = true;
            }   
                $( '#tinggi' ).val( response.tinggi_badan);
                $( '#berat' ).val( response.berat_badan);
            if(response.goldarah=='A'){
                $('input:radio[name=golonganA]')[0].checked = true;             
            }else if(response.goldarah=='B'){
                $('input:radio[name=golonganB]')[0].checked = true;
            }else if(response.goldarah=='AB'){
                $('input:radio[name=golonganAB]')[0].checked = true;
            }else{
                $('input:radio[name=golonganO]')[0].checked = true;
            }
                $( '#kontak' ).val( response.kontak);
                $( '#kontak_kel' ).val( response.nokontak_kel);
                $( '#kontak_em' ).val( response.email_kel);
                //--- assign id to hidden field ---
                $( '#userId' ).val( response.iduser );
            }
    });
} // end readUsers
```

My html code in client side: **settings.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />

 <link href="date/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="date/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="date/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="date/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    <script src="date/js/console.js"></script>
    <script src="jq/proses/set_ip.js"></script>
    <script src="jq/proses/editprofile/editprofile.js"></script>
    <script src="jq/proses/script.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        // create DatePicker from input HTML element
        $("#tanggal").kendoDatePicker({
        start: "date",
        depth: "year",
        format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
        });
    });
    </script>
<title>edc - e diabet consult</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Edit Profile</h1>
<p align="center" class="navigation">
<a href="home.html" title="Kembali ke CPanel">
<img src="ico/home.png">
</a>
<a href="pengaturan.html" title="Change Password">
<img src="ico/pass.png">
</a>
<a href="ranges.html" title="Set Target Range">
<img src="ico/setting.png">
</a>
</p>
<div id="updateDialog">
<form id="edit_profile" action="">
<p width="50%" align="center">
<strong>Nama Pasien</strong><br>
<input type="text" maxlength="350" id="nama" name="nama"><br>

<strong>Tempat Lahir</strong><br>
<input type="text" maxlength="350" id="tempat" name="tempat"><br>

<strong>Tanggal Lahir</strong><br>
<input type="text" maxlength="350" id="tanggal" name="tanggal" value="01-02-2013"><br>
<br>
<strong>Jenis Kelamin</strong><br>
<input class="float" type="radio" id="jeniskelaminL" name="jeniskelaminL" value="L">Laki-Laki 
<input class="float" type="radio" id="jeniskelaminP" name="jeniskelaminP" value="P">Perempuan<br><br>

<strong>Tinggi Badan (cm)</strong><br>
<input type="text" id="tinggi" name="tinggi"><br>

<strong>Berat Badan (kg)</strong><br>
<input type="text" id="berat" name="berat" value=''><br>

<strong>Golongan Darah</strong><br>
<input class="float" type="radio" id="golonganA" name="golonganA" value="A">A 
<input class="float" type="radio" id="golonganB" name="golonganB" value="B">B
<input class="float" type="radio" id="golonganAB" name="golonganAB" value="AB">AB
<input class="float" type="radio" id="golonganO" name="golonganO" value="O">O<br>
<br>

<strong>Kontak Pasien</strong><br>
<input type="text" id="kontak" name="kontak" value=''><br>

<strong>Kontak Keluarga</strong><br><br>
<strong>No.Telepon</strong><br>
<input type="text" id="kontak_kel" name="kontak_kel" value=''><br>

<strong>Email</strong><br>
<input type="text" id="kontak_em" name="kontak_em" value=''><br>

<input type="button" value="Simpan" onclick="update_profile()" id="simpan" class="button"/>
<input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button">

</p>
<br><br/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the question, but if you want the user to only select one value, the radio buttons should have the same name.

For example:

```
<input class="float" type="radio" id="golonganA" name="golongan" value="A">A 
<input class="float" type="radio" id="golonganB" name="golongan" value="B">B
<input class="float" type="radio" id="golonganAB" name="golongan" value="AB">AB
<input class="float" type="radio" id="golonganO" name="golongan" value="O">O<br>
```

Now only 1 value can be selected for "golongan" and you can get the value (A, B, AB or O) like this:

```
$gol = $this->input->post('golongan')
```

In the javascript, set the correct radio button like this:

```
$('input:radio[name=golongan][value='+response.goldarah+']')[0].checked = true;
```